# What is the equivalent of FilterDescriptor in NEST 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am in the process of upgrading NEST from 1.6.2 to 2.3.3. Getting type not found for **FilterDescriptor**, **FilterContainer**.

What are the equivalent types in NEST 2.3.3?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

---

Based on the response from @RussCam, here is what I got
in **1.6.2**

```
public static Func<FilterDescriptor<Property>, FilterContainer> AddressComponents(string address)
    {
        return filter => filter
            .Query(q => q
                .MultiMatch(multimatch => multimatch
                    .OnFields(
                        f => f.Address,
                        f => f.Address.Suffix("shingles"))
                    .Query(address)
                    .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
                    .Operator(Operator.And)
                )
            );
    }
```

to **2.3.3**

```
    public static Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Property>, QueryContainer> AddressComponents(string address)
    {
        return q => q
            .MultiMatch(multimatch => multimatch
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(p => p.Address)
                    .Field(p => p.Address.Suffix("shingles")))
                .Query(address)
                .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
                .Operator(Operator.And)
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent types in NEST 2.3.3 are `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>` and `QueryContainer`; [filters and queries merged in Elasticsearch 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0) into one concept, queries, that can be used in either a *query context* or a *filter context*, so the change in NEST reflects this.

[There's a blog post talking about the high level changes](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch), as well as some [documentation for 2.x clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html).

Comment: I am getting QueryDescriptor<T> type not found. QueryContainer is all good. Do I need to start using more specialised descriptor depending on the query we are building.

Comment: Apologies, should have been `QueryContainerDescriptor<T>` :) Will update now

Comment: Updated the question with sample conversion. @Russ.

Comment: @AntonyFrancis the updated version is missing the `Address` field in the fields

Comment: Updated with your feedback @RussCam